# npyscreen set value on selection

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a form F, where I define two widgets:

```
w1 = F.add(npyscreen.BoxTitle, name="Box Title:", max_height=6,width=32)
w1 . values = ["selection 1","selection 2"]
w2 = F.add(npyscreen.TitleFixedText, name = "Info:" , value="???", relx=50, rely=3 )
```

I want to display some text in the form *w2* depending on the cursor position of the form *w1*. For example if a user selected an item "selection 1", text to be displayed in the form *w2* is to be "extra info about selection 1". I have spend some time trying to understand how this can be achieved, but I did not succeed so far. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the value section should be:

```
w2 = F.add(npyscreen.TitleFixedText, name = "Info:" , 
value=self.w1.value, relx=50, rely=3 )
```